# Calling a video from Youtube.com in Flash through an XML

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I am trying to call a video from youtube.com in flash as2. The video link is stored in a external xml file. Flash works fine when i try to call a video with an exact flv location but it crashes whenever i try to call a youtube url. I am stuck with the codes. I was wondering if the video can start at a specific GMT that needs to be stored in xml. Please help.

Here is the flash code:

```
Security.allowDomain("www.youtube.com");
Security.allowDomain("*");

//initializing xml loading
// load the xml file
xmlData = new XML();
xmlData.ignoreWhite = true;
xmlData.onLoad = loadXML;
xmlData.load("videos.xml");

// parse the nodes of the xml into an array
function loadXML() {
    vidArray = new Array();
    aNode = this.firstChild.childNodes;
    len = aNode.length;
    for (var n = 0; n != len; n++) {
        vidArray[n] = aNode[n].attributes.url;
    }
}
output_vid.onEnterFrame = function() {
    trace(vidArray[0]);
    output_vid.contentPath = vidArray[0];
};
```

and here is the xml code (video.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<videos>
<video url="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jYa1eI1hpDE"/>
</videos>
```

Please help !!

Comment: The URL in your example leads to a HTML page, so you can't use it as the source for a video component in Flash. YouTube has an API for playing their videos in your own Flash applications, you should probably use that (I'm not sure they still support AS2).

Comment: @ Lars

Thanks for replying. Can you help me with an alternative?

Comment: You can use their API, they still support AS2, it seems: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/flash_api_reference_as2.html

Answer (score 0):

Load the XML into flash...
Get your url in a string, say "string3" for example..

string3 = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jYa1eI1hpDE"

now replace "watch?v=" with "v/"

```
var stringArray:Array=string3.split("watch?v="); 
string3 = stringArray.join("v/");
```

now string3 = "http://www.youtube.com/v/jYa1eI1hpDE"

That is the exact flv location on all youtube videos.... no need to do anything else.

Comment: That URL is to a swf, not a flv.

Comment: That's what I meant... anyways it should work, his was crashing because he was linking to a page, not a swf file... so the code should still work regardless of the terminology, but you are right... it is a swf ;) haha, don't know what I was thinking!